# What's the reason an angularjs httpprovider interceptor cannot access a custom http response header (CORS request)?

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, cors, interceptor

I have an *angularjs* 1.x application which communicates with a rest service using *jsons*.

Since the service sits under a different domain, I'm using *CORS*.

My *angular* application has a response interceptor that logs the response headers:

```
app.factory('responseInterceptor', ["$q", function ($q) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            console.log(response.headers()); // log the headers!!!
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}]).
config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('responseInterceptor');
}]);
```

Now everything works ok, but I'm not able to access custom http response headers

I'm using a http sniffer tool and I can see the headers in the servers response.

I'm pretty sure that this has something to do with CORS but I can't nail it.

The response headers (including CORS) look like this:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
MY-CUSTOM-HEADER: Go Home This Works
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: MY-CUSTOM-HEADER, CONTENT-TYPE
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2016 13:18:20 GMT
Content-Length: 14112
```

This is what I see in my console from the interceptor:

```
Object {pragma: "no-cache", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", cache-control: "no-cache", expires: "-1"}
```

Questions:

What's the reason I cannot see the `MY-CUSTOM-HEADER` when I log the response headers? Or other http response header that I can see on my sniffing tool. Who blocks me from accessing them on the `responseInterceptor`?

**Edit**: 
I've checked the same application under the same domain and COULD access the header with the same code. It does have something to do with CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after identifying that the issue was CORS, I've found I was missing an CORS http header called `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

After setting `Access-Control-Expose-Headers="MY-CUSTOM-HEADER"`, I was able to access that header.